# Cancel Process with Ctrl + C will not work in Terminal

Tags: server, command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I have just got myself a Ubuntu server and for some reason the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will not kill the process I am running. I have run this command on two terminals Cygwin and putty and logged in using ssh.

I can use the command locally and this is not a problem and also on other machines using Solaris. I have read some other posts on this site relating to this issue, however, my issue is still not resolved.

As the command works locally I am fairly confident that is not something in bash that needs to be set. (I use bash on all the machines I use). I am not trying to close processes like man or less using this command just scripts and standard processes where you expect it to work.

I have also tries <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and that does not work properly so not sure why it wont pick up any of these *VERY* useful commands. This is highly annoying for me.

I would like to learn as much as I can about Ubuntu as I have very little experience with it, if you have a solution can you include as much detail as possible?

Here is my stty -a:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; flush = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Is there any special process in particular where this happens?

Comment: Just whenever I log into my ubuntu server. This is with which ever user I use (I have two).

Comment: You mean you can not ctrl-C any program, or just a particular one?

Comment: any in this machiene

Comment: Could you provide the output of `stty -a`?

Comment: I have just relised that no commands using the ctrl button are working.

Comment: Well `stty -a` output looks correct, so it must be your window manager intercepting Ctrl+C and similar, so they never reach the remote tty.

Comment: well it would have to be something to do with the x11 download as it worked fine before. What could be in their to make such a change

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, the best cygwin tool is MobaXterm. It handles custom environment variables, and seamless X11 forwarding. I used it at work exclusively for 4 months and it sent <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> commands just fine.

I *much* prefer it to putty. Check it out at http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/